# Did "Novorossiya" have a de facto control over its declared territory between 2014 and 2015?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, territorial-dispute

Did the self-proclaimed "[Novorossiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novorossiya_(confederation))" have control over the territory it claimed during the time it existed (22 May 2014 to 20 May 2015)?

Comment: While I've added the quotes to make the grammar of the question more consistent with the cop out excuse for using the offensive term for Eastern Ukraine, I still thing it's a push question whose sole purpose is to attempt to normalize this highly offensive term.

Comment: @wrod It's not. Hitler was also bad, that doesn't make the word Third Reich offensive

Comment: Referring to *modern-day* Germany as "the Third Reich" would certainly be highly offensive.

Comment: @wrod who elected you to be the language police?  You make terminology remarks quite frequently, more so than most.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I do believe I am entitled to my opinion.  And since this site does have a policy of disallowing bigotry, the opinions on what is or isn't bigoted are on-topic.

Comment: @Probably Having said that, there is something different that makes me uneasy in this question.  "de facto control" is exactly the kind of terms one would use to build a case for having valid claims in negotiations or in a court of law.  Why exactly should the illegal territorial ambitions of a rebel area receive a lot of consideration?  If this is not - and I do not claim it is - intended to legitimize such claims maybe a little bit clarification would be welcome.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica this term has not been in common use in over a century.  It was resurrected and injected into the public discourse subsequently to Russia's 2014 invasion of Eastern Ukraine.

Comment: You are totally entitled to your own opinion.  As I am in noting that you often have objections about terms people use, more so than the average user seems to.  As far as Novo... being used in this Q - if it is necessary to ask a question about a rebel area's claims, it would seem expedient to refer to said rebel area by what it calls itself.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica it's a term injected by the Russian Federation, a foreign entity, in order to diminish Ukraine's standing as a sovereign entity.  These are facts.  Yes, I am entitled to my opinion.  And based on my opinion, formed on paying particular attention to this topic, I believe the term is being used not only to hearken to an ancient history, but to normalize a genocide.  My personal standard for "offensive" is quite well-formed.  Using in a modern-day context any term that has ever been used to *normalize* mass killings in the past, even the recent past, qualifies.

Comment: Question requires both expansion (e.g. defining terms and indicating research), and clarification of what it means by de facto control, e.g. monopoly of military power or civil administration, and relationship with the DPR and LPR vs centralised control.

Comment: @wrod That's true. However I'm asking about the time when the thing existed, according to Wikipedia, so it's like asking "Did the Third Reich have control over Norway in 1942?". Calling Germany the Third Reich would mean something very different.

Comment: @Probably I still wonder why this question is worth asking.  The wiki link shows areas of actual vs claimed control.  Any cursory research will show that the 2014-2015 troubles produced pro-RU riots in a number of areas but that the overall "control footprint" of Novo was mostly limited to areas separatists controlled as of Feb 2022.  To follow your example SE.History would reject a Q as trivial as "Did the Third Reich have control over Norway in 1942?" for lack of research.  Why not same for this Q?  Furthermore poor ephemeral Novo is not going to be @ negotiating table in 23-24 so who cares?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The image only implies that if you know the answer to the question, which I didn't, no googling has helped and no one provided links that would verify what folks here are saying. It's worth the time of anyone in the future googling that, just like me, out of curiosity. The way to fight autocrats is to make information accessible, asking whether questions are good to ask isn't a good cultural trend.

Answer (score 1):

No with the exception of DPR and LPR Novorossiya had never had control of any other teritory it claimed. There were some unsuccesful [uprisings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_pro-Russian_unrest_in_Ukraine) in Kharkov and Odesa regions, but they were never under control of Novorossiya.